# Multilingual comments form missing

Tags: forms, comments, i18n-l10n

I have a website in 2 languages. The site uses panels. The nodes Comments form & comments only shows in English and not in Greek.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [i18n comments](http://drupal.org/project/i18n_comments) can be used for this.  From the project page:

> A very simple module which would allow you to show all/any comments
>   attached to all node translations. Just a great way to communicate in
>   truly multi-lingual environments.
>
> For example I have node in English and Spanish. Drupal natural way
>   would be to show comments for en/es translation separately (attached
>   to en/es content). But i18n_comments will aggregate all English and
>   Spanish comments for any translations. It doesn't matter if user will
>   leave a comment to any node translation.

Comment: it is in beta version. will it work properly?